# Write a program that computes and prints the average of numbers in a text file

Tags: python

Write a program that computes and prints the average of numbers in a text file. I created a text file 'integers.txt' that has the numbers 5,4,3,2,1.

I need to define the average function

Define the main function which will include the following things

1. prompt user for input of text file name
2. open and read input file, can be done before or inside high order functions
3. use two high order functions

4.calculate and display averages and original list

5. call the main
6. exit the program

Here is what I have so far:

```
'Write a program that computes and prints the average of numbers in a text file.'

def getNumberList(filename):

    f = open(filename,'r')
    line = f.readline()
    numbers = line.split(',')#split the numbers separated by comma
    numberList = []#holds the integer value 
    for i in numbers:
        numberList.append(int(i))

    return numberList

def getAverage(numbers):

    sum = 0#stores the sum of the numbers in the list
    count = 0#keeps the count of numbers in the list
    for i in numbers:
        sum = sum + i
        count = count + 1

    average = sum/count#calculate the average
    return average

def main():

    #take input from the user
    filename = input("Enter filename : ")
    #get the numbers from the file
    numbers = getNumberList(filename)
    #get the average from the numbers list
    average = getAverage(numbers)
    #display the average
    print(average)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Not sure how to add the two higher-order functions or how to get it to print the original list. I tried `print(numberList)` with no luck.

Comment: If you want to print the original list, `print(numbers)` should work.

Comment: Also, what is a "high order function"?  How is it different from a plain function?

Comment: Higher order functions in Python : sorted, map, reduce, filter

Comment: Also i just realized that for some reason the program is not giving me the correct answer. I added up the numbers which equals 15 and then divided by 5(number of numbers) and it is giving me 5 which is the count not the average which should be 3

Comment: @John Gordon when i do that it just gives me the count [5]. Not sure if something is wrong somewhere in the code as i mentioned in my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

From this website: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/higher-order-functions-in-python/

> A function is called Higher Order Function if it contains other functions as a parameter or returns a function as an output i.e, the functions that operate with another function are known as Higher order Functions.

Try this:

```
def getNumberList(filename): # Define a function that returns a list of numbers with filename as paramater
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        strList = f.read().split('\n')
        numberList = [int(num) for num in strList]
    return numberList

def getAverage(filename, func): # Define a function that returns the average of the numbers from a file, with the filename and the function that returns numbers as parameters
    numbers = func(filename)
    return sum(numbers)/len(numbers)

def main():
    filename = input("Input the file name: ")
    average = getAverage(filename, getNumberList)
    print(average)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/2004g/Desktop/Python/HeatherMorgan_Unit3_Project6.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/2004g/Desktop/Python/HeatherMorgan_Unit3_Project6.py", line 20, in main
    average = getAverage(filename, getNumberList)
  File "C:/Users/2004g/Desktop/Python/HeatherMorgan_Unit3_Project6.py", line 15, in getAverage
    numbers = func(filename)

Comment: File "C:/Users/2004g/Desktop/Python/HeatherMorgan_Unit3_Project6.py", line 11, in getNumberList
    numberList = [int(num) for num in strList]
  File "C:/Users/2004g/Desktop/Python/HeatherMorgan_Unit3_Project6.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
    numberList = [int(num) for num in strList]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5\n4\n3\n2\n1\n'
>>>

Comment: @Heather The reason you got the error is because your post has `.split(',')`, making users think the numbers in the file are separated by commas, while in reality, they are split by newlines. I updated.

Comment: I still gett an error with line 11 here is what it said:"C:/Users/2004g/Desktop/Python/HeatherMorgan_Unit3_Project6.py", line 11, in getNumberList
    numberList = [int(num) for num in strList]
  File "C:/Users/2004g/Desktop/Python/HeatherMorgan_Unit3_Project6.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
    numberList = [int(num) for num in strList]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5\n4\n3\n2\n1\n'

Comment: @Heather Can you post the txt file?

Comment: @Heather Also, if you followed my answer, the error wouldn't make sense. It's saying we cannot put strings with `'\n'` into `int()`, while the `.split('\n')` would've already taken care of that.

Comment: i copied and pasted your program example into python and still got the error

Comment: @Heather The contents of the txt file matter too. Can you post it?

Comment: how do i add a file? the file is just the numbers 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

Comment: @Heather According to the error, it's `'5\n4\n3\n2\n1\n'`

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce
def numbersInFile(file_name):
    numbers=[]
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        num_list=file.read().splitlines()
        for i in num_list:
            numbers+=i.split(' ')
    return numbers
def summation(x,y): return x+y
def main():
    file_name=input('Enter the input file name: ')
    numbers=list(map(int,numbersInFile(file_name)))
    num_length=len(numbers)
    total=reduce(summation,numbers)
    average=total/num_length
    print(f'The average is {average}')


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

here's an example of how to add 2 high-oder functions reduce and map

```
from functools import reduce
fileName = input("Enter the input file name: ")
f = open(fileName,'r')
lyst = f.read().split()
intLyst = list(map(int,lyst))
Average = (reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,intLyst))/len(intLyst)
print("The average is ",Average)
```